# Probability distribution. How many exam must be grade until the proffesor find one that is all correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This problem said: Suppose that all of the students in a very large class are randomly guessing on a multiple choice test with 10 questions where each question has four possible answers. How many exams must the teacher grade, on average, before she finds one in which a student got every answer correct?

My work:

---

1) First I consider each test: 10 question and 4 possible answers.

Let X= # of correct answer.

I want to know the probability of this event,(independent and p is always the same) I apply a Binomial distribution. Therefore, I have:

B(10,1/4)  and  P(X=10)=  10Cn10 (1/4)^10 (1-1/4)^10 = 5.37 10^(-8)

---

2) I want to find n, how many test the teacher grade until she find one with all correct answer. [I stuck here] I believe is also a binomial, but I can approx. with a Poisson, any way . In this case I put Binomial,

Y=# exam with all correct answers   p=5.37 10^(-8)

P(Y=1)=nCn1 p^n (1-p)^n-1 = 1 (100%) she found the test.

***I don't know how to find n, or if my thought is correct or not. Thanks!***

Comment: Don't include subjective things like "a very hard test" in the title, that is not descriptive, and besides hardness is very relative.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of exams that must be graded before the teacher finds one with all answers correct and $E$ is the event that the *first* exam graded has all answers correct then: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E(X\mid E)P(E)+\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)P(E^c)$$

Note that: $$\mathbb E(X\mid E)=1\text{ and }\mathbb E(X\mid E^c)=1+\mathbb EX$$

This provides you a way to express $\mathbb EX$ in $P(E)$ wich can be calculated.

Comment: Before all. Thanks to answer.   I have some considerations that I can not understan if is correct or not. From my first step I know that to have all 10 correct anwers is p=5.37 10^-8 . Now, your X, is a geometric dist. then EX=1/p. is that correct ? However if I apply your equation, I have EX=1+{P(Ec)/P(E)} but how much is P(E), for my understanding your v.a. E is geometric. Sorry , I'm pretty lost. Thanks.

Comment: $X$ has indeed [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). My equation gives $\mu=1+(1-p)\mu$ hence $\mu=\frac1{p}$ as you remark. $P(E)$ is the probability that the first exam has only correct answers wich agrees with the $p$ that you calculated.